# Send request to Google App Script by cURL

Tags: curl, oauth, google-apps-script, authorization, google-authentication

I create custom Google App Script for spreadsheet, and I need to send GET request to that script. I want do this by cURL from terminal, but I stand against authorization problem. I read these articles:

[About auth](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth)

[OAuth2 google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

and more, but I didnt find simple solution.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Oauth client_secret" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files //error about invalid creadentials

curl https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?access_token=secret // error about required login

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer secret" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files // but how I can get Bearer? what is brearer?
```

Can somebody help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the official google appscript help on how to publish a script. publish to run as "me" with access to anyone, even anonymous. publishing gives you a special url you can then curl.

also read about contentService which you probably want to use if you need to return data.

the api you are currently using is unrelated.

Comment: thanks, do all like you say but get error https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/e1245041b7748549c90c, actually I dont want return any data, I just want to send that request, it will trigg some scritp mechanism

Comment: read well the guide and follow all steps including updating script version

Comment: there isnt enough info to help you. open a separate well documented question. this answer will work 100% on all cases.

Comment: @excluded_once Set you fetch to follow redirections.

Comment: I think the redirection is only needed to receive the response. debug and see if doGet gets hit or not. i have done the same curl and didnt need to follow redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to request to the Google API's instead of Apps Script. These API's need a proper Authentication mechanism.

What is the Apps Script you are trying to call? These links end with /exec. Did you deploy the script as a web-app, and give access to 'Everyone'?

Comment: this is not an answer. should go in comments

Comment: Sorry Zig. Finding my way around.

Comment: you can still delete it and move it to a comment. or risk a downvote (not mine)